# Pronouncing "re" and "le" at the end of words?

Tags: prononciation, e-caduc

*Livre*, *entre*, *autre*, *article*, *règle* are examples of what I'm talking about.

I've never been sure whether I should pronounce those final two letters. When a native speaker pronounces such words, sometimes I can hear them and sometimes I can't.

Comment: It depends on the situation.  Are you talking normally, singing, or are you angrily yelling at someone?

Comment: ....the second two.

Comment: Related answer: https://french.stackexchange.com/a/11979/79

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Dropping liquids after consonants (e.g. in words that ends with *-ble, -dre, -tre, -fle* etc.) is an *extremely* common feature of everyday pronunciation in French (Grevisse 14th ed., §36c). Pronouncing many final schwas would be the primary reason for the recognition of these consonants and is generally considered either an affectation or a dialectal feature.

Answer (score 6):

In French it's not the the `re` or `le` that is left unpronounced, but the final `e`.

Pronouncing `livre` is like pronouncing `livr`. Some people may actually force the last consonant and you get a sound like `livreu`.

Comment: Well in relaxed speech, you even drop the R in certain cases. Example :  if you want to say quickly "un livre de peinture", you could say either "un livr-e'd'peinture" (which sound a little ch'ti-ish) or more probably "un liv'de peinture".